# Trace a module line by line?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I'm trying to use WinDbg to trace my program (only one module in it), and log back the line numbers executed. I will automate the process later, but for now I just wish to walk through the code line by line.

I'm trying to see if I can use my automated debugger to calculate code coverage of an automation.

I have the correct symbols. How do I do this? Debuggers obviously have the capability to execute code line by line.

I've tried using `l+t`, `l+o`, `l+s`, `p` and `pr`. I've enabled source mode (`l+t`), but I do not see the source code in command window, and neither do I see any source window.

Comment: You need to add the pdb location and the source file location in windbg, this can be done using 'File>Symbol File Path...' and 'File>Source File Path...' using the gui, or ctrl+S and ctrl+P respectively. Alternatively you can do this using commands `.srcpath` and `.sympath`

Comment: @EdChum, yes I could do it now. Feeling stupid now :|. My sourcepath was not set, symbols were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the symbol and src path to windbg, it will not be able to resolve this normally.

You can either add the paths using the Gui:

'File>Symbol File Path...' 
and 
'File>Source File Path...' using the gui
or <kbd>ctrl+S</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd> respectively.

Alternatively you can do this using commands 
[`.srcpath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`.sympath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565407(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**cdb -lines -c "l+t;l+o;l+s;g main;p 12;q" printhello.exe**

```
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'l+t;l+o;l+s;g main;p 12;q'

Source options are d:
     1/t - Step/trace by source line
     4/s - List source code at prompt
     8/o - Only show source code at prompt

>    5:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[0]);
lets say hello to the world for    first time
>    6:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[1]);
lets say hello to the world for   second time
>    7:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[2]);
lets say hello to the world for    third time
>    8:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[3]);
lets say hello to the world for   fourth time
>    9:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[4]);
lets say hello to the world for    fifth time
>   10:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[5]);
lets say hello to the world for    sixth time
>   11:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[6]);
lets say hello to the world for  seventh time
>   12:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[7]);
lets say hello to the world for   eighth time
>   13:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[8]);
lets say hello to the world for    ninth time
>   14:         printf("lets say hello to the world for %8s time\n", count[9]);
lets say hello to the world for    tenth time
>   15: }½½½½½½½½■?¶
printhello!__tmainCRTStartup+0x10b:
004013a8 83c40c          add     esp,0Ch
printhello!__tmainCRTStartup+0x111:
004013ae 3975e4          cmp     dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],esi ss:0023:0013ffa4=000000
00
printhello!__tmainCRTStartup+0x116:
004013b3 50              push    eax
quit:
```